# Foolproof industry categorization for equities exchanges

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges

Some equity exchanges have a very exhaustive list of all the industries their issuers are involved in. This granularity is kind of nice at times, but often I find it preferable to have a simplified, more coarse representation of the industries. For illustration purposes here is an exchange with over 20 industries:

1. Electronic components
2. Non-ferrous metals
3. Electrical equipment
4. Chemical
5. Biotech
6. Machinery/equipment
7. Food/beverage
8. Computers
9. Auto
10. Defense
11. Non-bank financials
12. Utilities
13. Mining
14. Media
15. Ferrous metals
16. Transportation
17. Ag
18. Banks
19. Construction
20. Property
21. Appliances
22. Lighting
23. Construction materials
24. Commerce
25. Textiles
26. Tourism

This is just one example, other exchanges have their own taxonomy, usually varying between the type of exchange (tech-centric, ect). I would like to have a universal, foolproof method to dump the excessive number of categories into bins to make things more manageable. Ideally, I want to aim for four or five categories.

### Question

What is a safe, widely-recognized approach to recast the different breadth of industries at the exchanges into roughly four or five categories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From ["Industry vs. Sector: What's the difference?"](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/05/industrysector.asp)

> These two terms are sometimes reversed. But the general idea remains: one breaks the economy down into a few general segments while the other further categorizes those into more specific business activities. **In the stock market, the generally accepted terminology cites a sector as a broad classification and an industry as a more specific one.**

[Stock Market Sectors](https://www.fool.com/investing/stock-market/market-sectors/)

> There are 11 different stock market sectors, according to the most commonly used classification system: the Global Industry Classification Standard (GICS).

From [MSCI / GICS](https://www.msci.com/gics)

[image: GICS pyramid - sector vs industry]

Answer (score 3):

The smallest set that I would go with would be the 11 [SPDR sector ETFs](https://www.etfscreen.com/s_selects.php):

- Basic Materials
- Consumer Cyclical
- Consumer Defensive
- Energy
- Financials
- Healthcare
- Industrials
- Real Estate
- Technology
- Telecommunication
- Utilities